# How save allure report when Junit5 tests were launche via standalone

Tags: junit5, allure

Junit5 tests are launched in standalone.
I package test-project by command: `mvn clean package`.
Then run tests via command:

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.2.jar -cp 1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat-tests.jar --select-package com.example.tests
```

At the execution allure-reports directory was created, but all .json file are epmty.

How to configure pom.xml and assembly.xml files for saving allure reports?

pom.xml:

```
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-archive</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```